# Python Tesseract Segmentation Fault 11

Tags: python, segmentation-fault, tesseract

I am using tesseract and opencv to read images as part of a different program. I wrote this piece to try to work out the bugs I have with the main program. The test() function will get pretty much copied and pasted into the final program. The issue I'm having is that tesseract seems to quit python with Segmentation Fault 11. This happens intermittently. Sometimes this example code runs completely, sometimes it fails after 56 iterations (every time). 
Everything I installed is in homebrew (I followed these instructions: https://code.google.com/p/python-tesseract/wiki/HowToCompilePythonTesseractForHomebrewMacMountainLion)
After searching for solutions to my problem, I tried the instructions in this: http://www.janeriksolem.net/2011/12/installing-opencv-python-interface-on.html , and I'm pretty sure I did everything right, but I'm still getting occasional seg faults.

```
import time
import tesseract
import cv2
import cv2.cv as cv
import Image
def test():
    image0=cv2.imread("test.jpg")
    offset=20
    height,width,channel = image0.shape
    image1=cv2.copyMakeBorder(image0,offset,offset,offset,offset,cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT,value=(255,255,255)) 

    api = tesseract.TessBaseAPI()
    api.Init(".","eng",tesseract.OEM_DEFAULT)
    api.SetPageSegMode(tesseract.PSM_AUTO)
    height1,width1,channel1=image1.shape
    print image1.shape
    print image1.dtype.itemsize
    width_step = width*image1.dtype.itemsize
    print width_step
    #method 1 
    iplimage = cv.CreateImageHeader((width1,height1), cv.IPL_DEPTH_8U, channel1)
    cv.SetData(iplimage, image1.tostring(),image1.dtype.itemsize * channel1 * (width1))
    tesseract.SetCvImage(iplimage,api)

    text=api.GetUTF8Text()
    conf=api.MeanTextConf()
    image=None
    print "..............."
    return (text, conf)

for x in xrange(200):
    print "x: %d" %x
    test()
    print
time.sleep(1)
print "Done"
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a very late answer but I was having the same problem while working with OS X Lion, python2.7, OpenCV 2.4 and Tesseract 3.0

I found three issues while debugging using eclipse+pydev...

The first is that the image given to tesseract always has to be a binary image.

The second problem is `cv2.imread()` doesn't work sometimes and it simply returns an empty ndarray. I really don't know why this happens and if it is got something to do with running python in eclipse+pydev.

So when I tried to make use of the empty ndarray's `shape` and `dtype` I had null characters and this produced an empty iplimage while using `cv.SetData()`. And when `api.GetUTF8Text()` tried to work on this empty iplimage, everything broke down in a weird way and I got "Segmentation Error 11"

Thirdly, it turns out that cv2 and cv have a very different way of handling arrays and they have their axes switched around. So if you did something like...

```
image = cv2.imread('something.jpg',0) # flag = 0 is for converting to grayscale
image = cv2.threshold(image,128,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
height,width,channel = image.shape
```

then you need to do...

```
iplimage = cv.CreateImageHeader((width,height), cv.IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1)
cv.SetData(iplimage, image.tostring(),image.dtype.itemsize * (width)) #the number of channels is 1
```

and I see that you've tackled the third issue.

Strangely, if I have a code like `img0 = cv.fromarray(scr)` right after the line `scr = cv2.imread('textSample.jpg',0)` then everything works fine.

Have a go at the following code with the image "textSample.jpg" (at the bottom of this post) and uncomment the lines (except the first line which is not a comment) so that you can see what image your codes are working on. `scr`, `img0` and `img1` should eventually be the same:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import cv2
import cv2.cv as cv
import tesseract

scr = cv2.imread('textSample.jpg',0)
#img0 = cv.fromarray(scr)
#cv.SaveImage('img0.jpg',img0)

api = tesseract.TessBaseAPI()
api.Init(".","eng",tesseract.OEM_DEFAULT)
api.SetPageSegMode(tesseract.PSM_AUTO)

image = cv.CreateImageHeader((scr.shape[1],scr.shape[0]), cv.IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1)
cv.SetData(image, scr.tostring(), scr.dtype.itemsize*scr.shape[1])

#cv.SaveImage('img1.jpg',image)

tesseract.SetCvImage(image,api)
text=api.GetUTF8Text()
conf=api.MeanTextConf()

print text
print conf
```

you should get something like...

```
OE3456789
!"#$%&'()* .-./

76
```

[image: textSample.jpg]